# Auth not persisting in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have my auth doing this on login.

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    dd(Auth::user()); //this shows the user just fine, 
                      //which proves that the auth driver is working.
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

However, after redirecting to the dashboard.  It appears the auth isn't persisted.  If I do `dd(Auth::user())` or even just `Auth::check()` it returns null.

Here's the route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     Route::get('test',function(){
       dd(Auth::user()); //returns null
        echo Auth::user()->name; // returns Trying to get property of non-object
     });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

The weird thing about this is that last night it was working.  It kinda just magically stopped working.

Comment: The session is not necessarily persisted if you `dd` after `attempt`. What hapens if you just return an empty string as a response instead of your redirect, and manually go to the test route?

Comment: Also, instead of `attempt`, you could do some further debugging by calling `login` instead, and force login a user. This will at least circumvent the potential problem with the actual authorization. This is most probably a cookie or session problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is not an obvious one, specially coming from older versions of laravel.
Thanks to this link.
[Auth Session killed in Laravel 5.2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auth-session-killed-after-redirect-laravel-52)
I was able to solve it, so I'll post the answer to help others who encounter the same issue.

Originally I just had this in my routes.

```
Route::post('app/login', 'Auth\AuthController@doLogin');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
     Route::get('test',function(){
        dd(Auth::user());// was always returning null
     });
});
```

But, to get the login to persist, I had to do this

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web']], function () {
   Route::post('app/login', 'Auth\AuthController@doLogin');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
     Route::get('test',function(){
        echo Auth::user()->name;
     });
});
```

Apparently any route thats going to call or register a session needs to employ the 'web' middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "auth" middleware to your "test" route and try accessing it while logged in. It shouldn't give you any errors that way. If you try to access it without logging in, it should redirect you to whatever route is defined in the "auth" middleware.

By using "auth" middleware, you are basically ensuring that Auth::user() will always return a proper User instance.

Now, if this works then you can be sure that Laravel Auth is indeed persisting the user and the issue is somewhere else in your code.

I haven't noticed any issues with the Auth class in Laravel.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 uses the web middleware.  No need for the auth middleware.  If I add the Auth middleware however, like you said.  It just redirects me back to the login page.  What I find strange is that Auth attempt appears to return a valid login.  Its just the redirect that 'forgets it'.   So with the 'web' middleware, I just get a blank page on redirect.  And with the auth middleware, I get redirected back to login page.

Comment: Web middleware has things like CSRF and XSS protection, it doesn't also check if a user is logged in.

Just wanted to point out that you can actually check if Auth is doing what it should when logging in a user into the app by protecting that one route you have inside your group protected via "web" middleware, just to make sure that Auth is working correctly. If it is ( not allowing you access if not logged in ), then your issue is at some other place in your code :)

Comment: Ok, but even after adding the auth middleware, I just get redirected on login, back to the login page.  Even though a dd(Auth::user()) in the Auth controller shows a logged in user?  So what Im saying, is that the login seems to be working, for the one request, but on redirect, it doesnt persist, hence redirects back to the login page.  Tried session driver, database driver, file driver everything.  Nothing seems to work

Comment: Ok, I found the solution here....https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auth-session-killed-after-redirect-laravel-52  Apparently all routes that are going to hold sessions have to be inside the web middleware.  So I had to put my login route inside that middleware as well.  However, now Im getting a token mismatch error....lol  But at least the login part is solved.

Comment: Totally forgot about that :) You are getting token mismatch in your form, probably because you are not using _token field and adding it to that form ?

Comment: I do have a _token field.  Not sure why it was happening, but clearing my cookies, fixed it. lol