# Session is not started Laravel 5.3 Auth

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am trying to authenticate user against an API in Laravel 5.3.  It is not working.  Auth does not persist once the user redirects after login.

---

Routes are configured like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Users\DashboardController@index');
    });
    // Authentication routes...
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@postLogin');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@getLogout');

});
```

In LoginController.php I'm using

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
public function getLogin()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->login($request);
}
```

---

After login which is successfully saved in file, the session is not started for route `'/'`.

So on `'login'` route:

`dd($session);`  in Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard returns `#started : true`

```
Store {#153 ▼
 #id: "fo9Q8WuBio5BBus70WmzFPZmkXkjsYQlYEHsVHI4"
 #name: "laravel_session"
 #attributes: array:4 [▼]
 #bags: []
 #metaBag: MetadataBag {#144 ▼}
 #bagData: array:1 [▼]
 #handler: FileSessionHandler {#154 ▼}
 #started: true
```

}

but `#started` is false when the route is in `'auth'` middleware group (`'/'` in my case).

I checked some and `#started` is also false when I put the `'/'` route outside `'auth'` middleware group but calling `Auth::check()` in controller.

This problem seems to have existed in 5.2 ([Auth not persisting in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921210/auth-not-persisting-in-laravel-5-2)
), but the solution there not working for me.

Please help me understand why I can't access the `'/'` route after logging in.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

change kernel.php 'api'

```
api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
```

to

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ],
```